# Convert existing text to heading3 format in docx using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ms-word, python-docx

I have a code that has a table and i'm converting a particular cell that has text into bold format using below code,

```
cell = table.cell(0,1)
    for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            run.font.bold = True
            [need to add a code here to convert the same cell to heading3 format]
```

I'm lost here to convert the same cell to a heading3 format. I only get ***.add_heading*** which is not helpful in my case since it is a cell that already has text in it.

Answer (score 0):

A heading is just a paragraph with one of the heading styles applied to it.

```
paragraph.style = "Heading 3"
```

should do the trick.